# Javascript not working even when it is present in the source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check this link here : http://www.edu-leaders.com/search?page=2&per_page=8&search=text&sort=Relevance&utf8=%E2%9C%93

you can notice that there is a pagination at the bottom of the page, which is wrong as the links are not along with their hostname. So I tried a fix to add the hostname dynamically using javascript. Now the thing is if you run this code:

```
 $('.pagination a').each(function(i) {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if ((/^\/\//).test(link)){
            $(this).attr('href', link.replace(/\/\//,'/'));
        }
  });
```

from your console. Everything will become proper and the pages will start going to page 2 , 3 and so on.

The same code is present in the source code , if you can see on the bottom of the page. wrapped inside document ready. But that doesnt seem to work.

Can anybody find the reason for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script tag is outside the closing `</body>` tag, move it inside and it should work

Comment: Sir I tried moving the code inside head part, now also its not working, please have a look http://www.edu-leaders.com/search?page=2&per_page=8&search=text&sort=Relevance&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: oohhh I left out jquery, thank you for your answer sir. it works :)